# How to adjust the arrow head tip of a bezier curve?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I want to adjust the arrow head tip of a bezier curve on the left such that it looks like the one on the right.

As there is no  `\ncbezier` or `\pcbezier` available, I cannot use `nodesep` to adjust it. `arcsep` does not work as well.

Using `\psbezier{->}([offset=4pt]R)([offset=-4pt]CR)([offset=-4pt]CL)([offset=4pt]L)` is not perfect because it produces a new different bezier curve. In the right figure, can you see the filled region bounded by the first created bezier curve is not exactly enclosed by the second one?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{griddots=0,gridwidth=0.4pt,subgriddiv=10,subgridwidth=0.1pt}

\def\Common{%
    % define nodes  
    \pnode(0,0){L}
    \pnode(1;45){T}
    \pnode(!2 sqrt 0){R}
    \pnode[-0.5,0.75](T){CL}
    \pnode[0.5,0.75](T){CR}
    % draw a bezier curve
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linestyle=none]{\psbezier(R)(CR)(CL)(L)\closepath}
    % draw dots
    \pscircle(L){4pt}
    \pscircle(R){4pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1.45,1.25)
    \Common
    \psbezier{->}(R)(CR)(CL)(L)
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1.45,1.25)
    \Common
    \psbezier{->}([offset=4pt]R)([offset=-4pt]CR)([offset=-4pt]CL)([offset=4pt]L)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

So how to adjust it? More general question: Is it possible to put the arrow head to any point on the path (as in TikZ it is possible)?

Comment: I don't know pstricks, but Metapost handles this as follows. Save the original path, shorten it by the required amount (by using metapost primitives that allow you to traverse a certain distance on the path) and then draw the arrow. The same idea should work in pstricks as well.

Comment: @Karl's students Herbert has come up with a solution at http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa070.tex.

Comment: @SvendMortensen: You can make it as your answer and I will accept it to finalize the bounty and question.

Comment: Okay, but I haven't really done anything, I think. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herbert has come up with a solution on [his homepage](http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa070.tex).

Comment: But this solution used a trial-and-error approach that will be broken if I change the circle radius. :-)

Comment: Good point! I actually hadn't noticed that; I just looked at the picture and thought that it was a good solution (it usually is when Herbert is the author).